# Clickhouse DB Error when using Multiprocessing.Pool

Tags: python, multiprocessing, clickhouse

I am trying to speed up sequential execution of clickhouse queries using parallel programming. My code is follows:

```
from cimport Pool
from clickhouse_driver import Client

client= Client(**conn_dct)

def foo(arg_1, arg_2):
    client.insert(f'INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES {arg_1}, {arg_2}')

args = [(arg_11, arg_21)].
pool = Pool(os.cpu_count()-1)
pool.starmap(foo, args)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

I encountered

```
clickhouse_driver.errors.ServerException: Code: 614.
```

Can you please tell me what the problem could be? Perhaps you should use another library for parallelization of queries

Answer (score 0):

the error says that it is server exception. so, check the server logs